# A couple of questions about android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently downloaded android studio and after following some youtube tutorials by TheNewBoston I have found a couple of errors occuring.

Firstly I can't seem to add widgets to my app screen. When I drag them onto the phone screen on the xml file in design view it does not let me place them. Instead when I click on a widget and drag it over the phone screen a circle with a line through it appears. I can provide a screenshot of this if it helps.

The second problem is that some classes cannot be instantiated. Below is a screenshot of this.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwTUt.png)

Sorry if these are basic or commonly asked questions but I haven't been able to find solutions for these problems by myself looking online. Thanks to anyone who helps me.

EDIT:

Here are the contents of the **build.gradle** file for my app

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also here is a screenshot of the **sdk tools** I have installed. I have only the platform for 6.0 installed.
[sdk tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwTUt.png)
Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it :).

Comment: I used Droidio for awhile and liked it (although the Googlers hate it when I call it Droidio); anyway, you might find something useful here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/775821/The-Easiest-Way-to-Create-a-Layout-for-an-Android

Comment: I know that isn't an actual solution, but changing API level of display helped getting rid of stuff like this in my case. You have level 23 set (toolbar at the top of design window). I would usually set it to 20 or so and it would work...

Answer (score 0):

According to second problem, it seems to you don't have all necessary dependencies declared in `build.gradle` (so Android can't initialize these views) or you have already declared older version of Android Support Library like 21.x (I guess you installed it before adding these views).

Open your `Standalone SDK Manager` and check which version of build tools, android sdk you've allready have and if android support library was already installed.

Please, also edit your post and put a content of your;s project `build.gradle`file to check if I am wrong with my thoughts.

According to first, the 'problem' might be with kind of layout you choose. Different layouts behave in different way. Please check putting views on  'LinearLayout','RelativeLayout', 'GridView' ScrollView and more...

I've already using more .xml files than WYSIWYG editor. In that way, you'd learn more. 'Preview' I am using only to check how do my changes look like.

Of course, additional screenshots describing this problem are very welcome.

Comment: Also one more screenshot because cannot post more than 2 links in a single post. Here is a screenshot of trying to place widgets. I tried editing the layout through the text view of my projects xml file but I can't seem to get it working.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/AodOb.png

Comment: Please check it step by step and compare your files with attached here code [Introduction to Coordinator Layout on Android](https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/). It seems like I said before, Android does seem to not have all required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to add widgets to the app screen than probably might have not selected the layout first or try selecting lesser API it might help, if not let me know or share the screenshot of problem.